# sending a column from database table to another activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I am exctracting data from sqlite database and i need to transfer a column exctracted from select statment to other activity on a textview. How do i do it. Here's my code.

```
    db=database.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT lusername, lpwd, lname FROM login WHERE
    lusername=userfield.getText().toString(),lpwd=pwdfield.getText().toString()",null);

    if(c!=null)
    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomePage.class);
            intent.putExtra("TITLEBAR", lname);
    }
```

i want lname(column) to go to next activity's textview.

Comment: Is your database query worked? If yes then I know new method for select query..

Comment: it says the database already exists. how do i solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I doubt on your select query whether its worked or not.. 
But you told "I am extracting data from sqlite database" fine,

then just make a `String[] of lname` column's values from your database cursor then pass that `String[]` to other activity using `intent` like,..

**Create intent:**

```
Intent intent_name = new Intent(this, intent_name.class);
intent_name.putStringArray("key",string_array);
```

**Then in your intent_name.class do:**

```
String[] array = getIntent().getStringArray("key");
```

Comment: thanks user370305 :)
before doing all what u said, i initialized the cursor to zero'th position.

Comment: Thats why I mentioned your query doesn't work.. I think post a new question and put stacktrace of errors from logcat in question..

Comment: the actual query


        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT lname FROM login WHERE lusername= " + "'" + userfield.getText().toString() + "'" +"AND"+ "lpwd= " + "'" + pwdfield.getText().toString()+"'", null);